# Why this program going to infinite loop?

Tags: c, comma-operator

When i place `i<0,5` in the condition part of for loop in following code

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0;i<0,5;i++)
    printf("%d\n",i);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `i<0,5` evaluates to the value of the `5` . Which is true.

Comment: if the condition became as i<5 then it will not leads to infinite loop right?? but here it going to infinite loop

Comment: `i<5` would not lead to an infinite loop unless i is always less than 5.  But `i<0,5` is not the same as `i<5`, nor is it the same as `i < (0,5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is `5` is always `true`.
Please refer the following code disassembled from yours.
The condition part is referring just `5`.

`move eax, 5` is saving 5 to `eax` register.
`test eax, eax` is comparing between `eax` and `eax`.
It must be always same. So, It's always true.

```
009318FA  mov         eax,5
009318FF  test        eax,eax  
00931901  je          main+56h (0931916h)
```

And It is full code:

```
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 0, 5; i++)
009318E8  mov         dword ptr [i],0  
009318EF  jmp         main+3Ah (09318FAh)  
009318F1  mov         eax,dword ptr [i]  
009318F4  add         eax,1  
009318F7  mov         dword ptr [i],eax  
009318FA  mov         eax,5  
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 0, 5; i++)
009318FF  test        eax,eax  
00931901  je          main+56h (0931916h)  
            printf("%d\n", i);
00931903  mov         eax,dword ptr [i]  
00931906  push        eax  
00931907  push        offset string "%d\n" (0937B30h)  
0093190C  call        _printf (093104Bh)  
00931911  add         esp,8  
00931914  jmp         main+31h (09318F1h)
```

Comment: Can I get some more explanation as I am not familiar with that machine level code. When i executed it , it going to infinite loop why that is happening and what operation is going there??

Comment: @RaviTeja `,` means multiple operations in same line code. You wrote 2 operations as the condition part of `if statement`. In this case, Compiler applies one of operations. So, I converted it to machine level code to make sure which one is applied. From `i < 0, 5`, `5` is applied because C compiler reads codes by left to right. And, I added more explanation in my answer about machine code.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the loop to stops after 5 iterations you have to write

```
for(i = 0;i<5;i++)
   printf("%d\n",i);
```

As suggested you by [melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene), the comma operation is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do)